# sorting a list of tuples in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a set of tuple key,value pairs which look like this:

```
X=[(('cat','mouse'),1),(('dog','rat'),20),(('hamster','skittles),67)]
```

which I want to sort in order of the second item in the tuple. Pythonically I would have used:

```
sorted(X, key=lambda tup:tup[1])
```

I also want to get the key,value pair with the highest value, again, pythonically this would be simple:

```
max_X=max(x[1] for x in X)
max_tuple=[x for x in X if x[1]==max_X
```

however I do not know how to translate this into a spark job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
X.max(lambda x: x[1])
```

You could also do it another way, which is probably faster if you need to sort your RDD anyway. But, this is slower if you don't need your RDD to be sorted, because sorting will take longer than just telling it to find the max.(So, in a vacuum, use the `max` function).

```
X.sortBy(lambda x: x[1], False).first()
```

This will sort as you did before, but adding the `False` will sort it in descending order. Then you take the first one, which will be the largest.

Comment: thank you, for some reason I could not find the max function

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out in the 2 minutes since posting!

```
X.sortBy(lambda x:x[1]).collect()
```

Comment: but I have yet to figure out the max function